# Polymorphism: Accessing derived member function from base pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Given the following scenario:

```
#include <vector>

struct Widget
{
    void doThing()
    {
       ...
    }
};

struct SpecialWidget : public Widget
{
    void doSpecialThing()
    {
        ...
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Widget*> widgets;
    widgets.push_back(new Widget());
    widgets.push_back(new SpecialWidget());
    ...

    for(auto& w : widgets)
    {
        w->doThing();
        //Also need to call doSpecialThing() if element is a SpecialWidget
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is the correct thing to do here declare `doSpecialThing()` as a virtual function inside the base class `Widget` and have it do nothing? I am fairly sure the answer is no. In which case, is there a better approach to this problem?

Kind regards

Comment: Do you want `SpecialWidget` to `doSpecialThing()` instead of `doThing()`?  If so, just override `doThing()`.  If you want `doSpecialThing()` to `doThing()` and something else, override again and explicitly call `Widget::doThing()` before hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual functions should always be in the base class. Adding the `virtual` keyword in any class that's not a base class won't have any effect.

We can also call the base class version of a function by explicitly specifying the scope of the function in question.

If you're okay with changing `doSpecialThing` to be called `doThing`, your code can simply become:

```
struct Widget
{
    //make virtual for dynamic function binding with Widget pointers
    virtual void doThing()
    {
       ...
    }
};

struct SpecialWidget : public Widget
{
    void doThing()
    {
        Widget::doThing();
        ...
    }
};
```

Or if you want to keep it as `doSpecialThing`:

```
struct Widget
{
    //make virtual for dynamic function binding with Widget pointers
    virtual void doThing()
    {
       ...
    }
};

struct SpecialWidget : public Widget
{
    void doThing() {
        Widget::doThing(); 
        doSpecialThing();
    }

    void doSpecialThing()
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of different function names you are interchanging but from what I gather you want to have a derived class call its own doThing() and then have the base class call its doThing() right after, which is perfectly acceptable.

```
#include <vector>

 struct Widget{
     virtual void doThing()
     {
         cout << "Base"  << endl;
     }
 };

 struct SpecialWidget : public Widget
 {
     void doThing()
     {
         cout << "Derived" << endl;
         Widget::doThing();
     }
 };
```

Although I'm slightly rusty on my C++ I believe this will work, the output would be

```
Derived
Base
```

Answer (score 0):

As an expansion of my comment, if you want a `SpecialWidget` to do something special along with the base `doThing()`, a better way would be to override `doThing()` in `SpecialWidget` as follows:

```
struct SpecialWidget : public Widget
{
    void doThing()
    {
        Widget::doThing();
        ...
    }
};
```

and call everything else as normal.